# Visualising/getting inuition for, the manifold resulting from these geodesics?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, curvature, geodesics

This is related to another post of mine. I know that the geodesics for flat Euclidean Space are straight lines. But I want to take these curved geodesics and tried to work backwards to determine the geometry of the manifold that results from these geodesic paths going across it. I can't really visualise the manifold because there's a lot going on. So how would I build up a representation of the manifold that matches up with these geodesics running across it? What would the steps be to calculate the metric of this space? Is there enough information given by the geodesics to provide a good representation of the manifold? Any other interesting questions you could ask about this graph? What topological information could I learn from these geodesics?

[image]